# ProgressDialog, вывод информации при работе метода

Tags: android

У меня есть метод, который должен выполнится n-раз. Как проще всего показать пользователю моего приложения через ProgressDialog+горизонтальный прогрессбар, что процесс идет (метод выполнился n+1 раз)?

Сейчас информация выводится,  только она никак не связана с выполнением метода. То есть,  к примеру,  метод должен быть выполнен 77 раз. Пользователь запускает выполнение метода,  ему показывается ProgressDialog и ProgressBar, который показывает счет от 1 до 77. Но когда процесс доходит до значения 77, метод успевает выполнится всего 52 раза. После этого метод выполняется далее, но ProgressDialog уже закрыт (якобы процесс завершен).

Код такой:

```
pd = new ProgressDialog(ClearActivity.this);
pd.setTitle("Выполняем..");
pd.setMessage("Удаление");
pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
pd.setMax(100);
pd.setIndeterminate(true);
pd.show();
h = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        pd.setIndeterminate(false);
        if (pd.getProgress() < pd.getMax()) {
        // Тут выполняется метод
            pd.incrementProgressBy(1);
            h.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 1000);
        } else {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }
};
h.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 2000);
```

Comment: ну сейчас у тебя прогресс в PB меняется просто каждые 2 секунды, а тебе нужно менять в зависимости от прогресса выполнения твоего метода.

Comment: Это понятно. Именно поэтому я и задал вопрос, так как не знаю, как привязать результат выполнения метода к прогрессбару.

Comment: код метода можно увидеть?

Comment: Вот к примеру, я хочу вывести все 70 элементов массива. Задаю в начале int n = 0, после этого в самом коде , где я указал место для метода, пишу так: System.out.println("Вывод: " + mass[n]); n = n + 1;

Comment: Ну значит нужно перед началом вывода массива создать прогресс диалог, а во время вывода при увеличении N изменять прогресс.

Comment: И хочу,  чтобы индикатор прогресса увеличивался на 1 в то время, когда выведен элемент массива. В этом вся загвоздка. Сорри,  если сразу толком не объяснил.

Comment: Если вы знаете, точное кол-во выполнения методов, тогда каждый раз когда выполняется метод ++, и это значения передавайте к прогресс бару. А размер бара будет равен максимальному кол-ву выполнений. Что именно не получается?

Comment: Это все я передаю. Только значения прогрессбара идут в независимости от выполнения метода. А я хочу сделать так,  чтобы если метод выполняется,  к примеру,  54-й раз - то пусть в, прогрессбаре также индикатор должен находится на значении 54. Но сейчас увы, его значение может быть 68 либо он уже вообще завершил свою работу.